# Clear persistence between tests in Spring with OpenJPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, openjpa

I am using Spring Data JPA and HSQLDB, with OpenJPA as JPA provider.

Created 2 test classes (`SpringBootTest`) which are executed one after another, both using same repository to save (using `save()` of `CrudRepository`) entities.

```
@Entity(name = "theentity")
public class TheEntity {
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Id
   private int id;
}


@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
   final JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
   tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
   return tm;
}
```

The problem is, when I run the second test class I expect to clear the persistence including the starting value of `identity` column.

But the above doesn't happen.

When using hibernate, adding annotation :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

above the test class does whole the work for me (rollbacks), unfortunately, the annotation doesn't do anything with OpenJPA.

Is there an alternative method for this?
Maybe need to add some property inside `persistence.xml` or something to `TransactionManager` bean?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `@DataJpaTest` annotation ? This is based on the assumption that you are using spring boot.

> By default, data JPA tests are transactional and roll back at the end
>   of each test.

From the documentation

> Data JPA tests may also inject a TestEntityManager bean, which
>   provides an alternative to the standard JPA EntityManager that is
>   specifically designed for tests.

Examples and details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test)

Comment: will it be possible to share a sample project ?